# MySQL: Getting inaccurate results when mixing JOINS

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 MySQL tables. Please check the structure below.

**Patient**

idPatient (int - primary key)

name (varchar)

age (varchar)

---

**Comobility**

idcomobility (int - primary key)

idPatient (int - foreign key)

idComobilityItems (int - foreign key)

---

**ComobilityItems**

idComobilityItems (int - primary key)

items (varchar)

---

The `ComobilityItems` contains values like "Heart Disease", "Kidney Disease" etc. The `Comobility` table simply holds its foreign key.

Please check the below SQL code

```
select patient.`idpatient`,
comobility.`comobility_items_idcomobility_items`
from patient
LEFT JOIN comobility ON patient.`idPatient` = comobility.`idPatient`
```

This returns be thousands of records. However I need the `comobilityItems.items` instead of `comobility.`comobility_items_idcomobility_items`.  I tried it like below.

```
select patient.`idpatient`,
comobility.`comobility_items_idcomobility_items`
from patient
LEFT JOIN comobility ON patient.`idPatient` = comobility.`idPatient` 
INNER JOIN comobilityItems ON comobility.idComobilityItems = comobilityItems.idComobilityItems
```

Anyway, this didn't work as expected because it has eliminated most of the results I was getting. Some patients do have `comobility` while some don't that is the reason I have used the `LEFT JOIN` for the `comobility` table. By using this code, I tried to replace the foreign key value in `comobility` table with the real values, but the `INNER JOIN` somehow messed up things.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Eg we cannot know what "as expected" means because you neither clearly explain nor give an example of what output you want given some input. PS The inner join after the left join is only going to return rows that satisfy its ON condition. PS Please consider using short aliases--eg p, c, ci. Also there is some typo involving "comobility_items_idcomobility_items" and an errant backquote.

Answer (score 0):

Add the extra table as a LEFT JOIN also

```
select
       patient.`idpatient`
     , comobility.`comobility_items_idcomobility_items`
     , comobilityItems.items
from patient
LEFT JOIN comobility ON patient.`idPatient` = comobility.`idPatient`  
LEFT JOIN comobilityItems ON comobility.idComobilityItems = comobilityItems.idComobilityItems
```

If you have data that "hangs off" a left joined table, than that extra information also must be left joined. If you don't (as you discovered) you "suppress" the outer join and create the conditions that equate to an inner join.

Comment: While true, I sense that this isn't quite what the OP's after, but I guess we'll see.

Comment: Well, yes, this is not what I asked. This simply generated the `comobility_items" list, one after another, without any relate to the patient

Comment: **show us some data** please (for each table) (omit or hide patient names etc. or make it for Fred Flintstone)   (don't use images of data and place this information into the question) The data model you gave us says the relationships are Patient > Comobility > ComobilityItems